# ASP.NET MVC Core 2 Dynamic Forms inside 1 Main Form

Tags: c#, forms, asp.net-core, viewmodel

This may be kind of a long question and I am a beginner but I am stuck and trying to understand how to build a real world app in ASP.NET MVC Core. I thought it would be simple enough to build a Testing App, but have run into a bit of a snag when it comes to creating a form. I have looked but haven't found anything close to my situation, but maybe I am overthinking this or going about it the wrong way.

First I have 3 models Test, Question, and Answer

```
public class Test
{
 public int ID {get; set;}
 public string Name {get; set;}
}

public class Question
{
  public int ID {get; set;}
  public int TestID {get; set;}
  public string QuestionText {get; set;}
}

public class Answer
{
  public int ID {get; set;}
  public int QuestionID {get; set;}
  public string AnswerText {get; set;}
  public bool IsAnswer {get; set;}
}
```

I also have tables to link these together

```
public class TestXQuestion
{
  public int ID {get; set;}
  public int TestID {get; set;}
  public int QuestionID {get; set;}
}

public class QuestionXAnswer
{
  public int ID {get; set;}
  public int QuestionID {get; set;}
  public int AnswerID {get; set;}
}
```

So I understand that in order to use multiple models in a view you need to have a ViewModel. I have grasped the concept of how to display data from multiple models using a VM, but I'm struggling to flip that back around and build a form with it. So if I want to be able to add a Test and add multiple questions and then add multiple answers to the questions. Here was where my thought process was:

TestViewModel

```
public class TestViewModel
{
  public Test Test {get; set;}
  public virtual IList<Question> Questions {get; set;}
  public virtual IList<Answer> Answers {get; set;}
}
```

So then in my create.cshtml I already used scaffolding for the form with the Test stuff.

```
<form asp-action="Create">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label asp-for="Test.Name" class="control-label"></label>
    <input asp-for="Test.Name" class="form-control" />
  </div>
  <div class="form-group>
    //Need logic here to add form for questions and answers 
  </div>
</form>
```

My TestController Create() method is the default method right now as well. Obviously I need some kind of Add Question button to add another question form to the test form, and would need to iterate through it. Then within the question form would also need similar functionality to add multiple answer fields as well. Then would obviously need to be able to get all the data and save it to it's respective tables.

So I was hoping that someone could point me in the right direction of how to go about accomplishing this? Or maybe someone could let me know if I'm overcomplicating this and there is a simpler way to get the same result. Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Are you trying to allow the user to create a test, or take a test, or both?

Comment: Right now I just want the user to be able to create a test.

Comment: In my opinion and that is what it is, I would create the model to be of type test, inside test class have a list of questions, and inside each question class a list of answers. Then you would need to use model binding in the form to pass it back to your server controller.